# Finding first integer or float number in a column vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, find

I would like to know that if there if any function in Matlab which finds the first integer value or first float value in a vector?
for example if we assume

```
w =

1.0000
0.9920
0.9995
0.1055
0.1191
0.0240
0.9999
0.0573
0.9811
1.0000
```

it would return `indx = 2` for float number.

Comment: One way to get your desired output: `find(double(uint8(w)) - w);`

Comment: @scmg: But only works from `1` to `255`.

Comment: then use `uint64`, or `int64` hehe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find(mod(w,1)>0,1,'first')
```

Use `mod` to identify non integer values, then use `find` with `first` option.